# I want my program to detect when the user clicks submit button on a website via uiwebview (iphone)

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I want to detect when the user click on submit button (after entering username and password) on the website via my uiwebview. I need to detect this action in order to retrieve the cookies from the logged in version of the webpage right after the user information is submitted.

I think this detecting thing involves setting delegate for the webview and writing some javascript operation via objective-c. I am not sure though.

How would you solve this problem? Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the part of the code for the webpage:

```
<form id="login-email" class="badge-login-form" action="https://9gag.com/login" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="jsid-login-form-csrftoken" name="csrftoken" value="999d68db0f5ed15d8966b66f23a52c3b"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="jsid-login-form-next-url" name="next" value=""/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="location" value="1"/>
                    <p class="lead">Log in with your email address </p>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="jsid-login-email-name">Email</label>
        <input id="jsid-login-email-name" type="text" name="username" value="" autofocus="autofocus"/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="login-email-password">Password</label>
        <input id="login-email-password" type="password" name="password" value="" />
                </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" onclick="GAG.GA.track('login-signup', 'login', 'login-form');"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set yourself as the delegate of the UIWebView, you can implement the method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    // this is the url you are about to load

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @user3074248 if it worked for you, could you mark this as best answer?

Comment: could you please describe how I could actually catch the action of the user clicking submit button the website, with this method? Thank you in aadvance!

Comment: @user3074248 when you click the submit button, your webview will attempt to load the page that is linked to by the button. At that point, this method will be called. You can compare the URL to the URL you are expecting to load on submit to see if it is the right request.

Answer (score 0):

If you use separate forms for each set of inputs, you can use 'onsubmit='

```
<form onsubmit="your_function_here "id="login-email" ... >
```

and if the user clicks submit or presses enter, your_function will be invoked

Just an idea, hope it helps

Comment: thank you it should help! just one question, how can I implement this in objective-c, i mean how can I write javascript via objective-c? Thank you very much in advance!